# How to autocomplete and perform contains for same field

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to use the autocomplete functionality which I have in place using the following mappings

analysis : filter : placename_ngram : max_gram=15, min_gram = 2, type = edge_ngram
analyzer :index: filter : lowercase, placename_ngram, tokenizer : keyword
placename_search : filter: lowercase: tokenizer keyword

This works great for type ahead but when I'm trying to find a value like "contains in" it doesn't return the record.

Such as
If I'm doing a text query on "Lake".

I will only get

Lake...
Lake Wood,

But will not get
Smithtown Lake

I have the field setup as multi-field and can do wildcard to find the values but not sure if this is efficient.

I believe I can use NGRAM but that seems like alot of overhead considering I only need index terms by whitespace (or by word).  Not every permetation.

Any thoughts?

When I change the tokenizer on both to "standard"....It will then find these records...but my autocomplete gets messed up and brings back Smithtown Lake  when typing Lak..... (which in this case I don't want).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [question where they were doing 2 different queries on the same field.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606546/elasticsearch-how-to-search-with-different-analyzers/)

Basically you are there, but you need to write 2 different queries, one for autocomplete-time and the other for full-blown-search-time.

You even describe wanting to have "Smithtown Lake" returned during search but not during autocomplete, you **need** to have different queries you want different results!

Answer (score 0):

I think Shingles is exactly what you are looking for. You can say it is NGram for Terms. [Checkout this.](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html)